# Setting text to ToolbarWindow324 Control of Save as Dialog?

Tags: autohotkey

Help with setting text to `ToolbarWindow324` Control of Save as Dialog?

```
5::
ControlGetText, ThisPath, ToolbarWindow324, ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe notepad.exe
Tooltip, Current Directory is : %ThisPath% 
Return
```

This snippet above programmatically gets me the current path of the dialog. I would like to set the path using this method.

So I tried the snippet below, Nothing seems to happen. I've searched online and I could not find any solutions using this method. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
5::
ControlSetText, ToolbarWindow324, Test123, ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe notepad.exe
Return
```

I know that on this same dialog. I can for example, set the path using the file name region I specifically need to do it this way.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may either be a ControlSetTextEx function (its been awhile since I dealt with Window handles)

Worse you may be dealing with a RichEdit control, which has a protected setting to prevent the text from being changed, its a bit more complicated than I can write a simple answer for...but Microsoft actually does a good job for once on this one.

Here is a link, the thing you are looking for is EN_PROTECTED specifically, but at the bottom of the page is a link to a full example of all controls in Visual C++.

Note: I know your using the control functions themself but the basic API will still function if returned a proper window handle or have a similar function on the controls function list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/format-text-in-rich-edit-controls

Comment: I think you answered what I was not able to set text to that control because of `RichEdit control`. I am just now getting into the world of programming so I think  C++ is above my paygrade. I do plan to get learn that as my main language in good time. Just out of curiosity though,  Would beginner or at least intermediate knowledge of C++ be sufficient to follow you? Thanks!

Comment: @Netmano93 - Were you able to use the reference to find yourself a working answer? I knew you weren't using C++ but I learned all my Window Handle coding back in Visual Basic 6, and from the layout of your code I figured it would make for a good enough general reference for you to figure out the answer you were looking for. You shouldn't mark it as answered if you didn't find a solution for your own problem. As for following me, I haven't been a member long enough to even know you could in truth...so I may not be the best choice. Could you? I can't say I'm beyond Intermediate myself, if that.